# Seeking decadal climate and ocean data for Europe

Tags: raster, data, climate, europe

Where can I find 'decadal' climate and ocean data for Europe that I can download and use directly in ArcGIS Desktop?

Specifically, I am looking for mean annual temperature, sea surface temperature, and salinity raster data for the decades from 1960 onwards.

Comment: You are looking for dekad data, but you mention mean annual temp? How come? Or probably you are looking for decad sst and salinity? And for annual mean temp is just 1 data for 1960 onward. If that the case, for annual temp you can check worldclim data

Answer (score 1):

You will find a lot of open data using our free Ocean Data tool http://marinexplore.com/explore/

You can select area by location name and narrow selection by polygon tool if need.
After previewing data online you will be able to generate a download with CSV file for in-situ measurements and NetCDF file for gridded data.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the available gridded dataset that includes your data is in this list:
http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/data/gridded/

Comment: Thanks for the source for a lot of useful GIS data. Unfortunately, I was unable to locate the data I am interested in, i.e. decade format.

Answer (score -1):

You could try here [University of East Anglia Climate research people](http://uea.ac.uk/cru/data/temperature/#datdow) They have a mass of data.